# numpy 64bit support in PTVS and numpy System.Int64 casting

Tags: .net, numpy, 64-bit, ironpython, scipy

I am trying to write some code with IronPython and numpy that calls a .NET assembly.
Version info:
numpy-2.0.0-1
scipy-1.0.0-2
IronPython 2.7.1

I installed scipy and numpy according to the instructions given here:

http://www.enthought.com/repo/.iron/

When I try to run with ipy64.exe I get the following:

```
Failed while initializing NpyCoreApi: BadImageFormatException:An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000
B)
NumpyDotNet stack trace:
  at NumpyDotNet.NpyCoreApi.GetNativeTypeInfo(Int32& intSize, Int32& longsize, Int32& longLongSize, Int32& longDoubleSize)
  at NumpyDotNet.NpyCoreApi..cctor()
```

Everything runs with ipy.exe. Is the current version of numpy for IronPython not 64-bit compatible?

The root problem I am investigating (may or may not be related to above) involves invoking a .NET assembly method that requires a System.Int64 as an argument. The python native int works fine but when invoking with a numpy.int32 (under ipy.exe) the implicit cast fails with:

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: data_type_tests
   System.Array[Int64](listValues)
TypeError: expected Int64, got numpy.int32
```

The code I am executing is:

```
values = array([1,2,3,4,5])
listValues = list(values);
System.Array[Int64](listValues)
```

If I make a list directly, i.e. values = [1,2,3,4,5]
then the above runs.

Any suggestions on converting the numpy array to a System.Array[Int64] under 32 bit or comments on the state of the numpy 64 bit support on IronPython?

Comment: More specifically: I am wondering how I cast a numpy array type back to a python list that contains <type 'int'> elements instead of <type 'numpy.int32> elements (since the base int type works with the api mentioned above). I would like to do this conversion in a performance-wise way. Manually iterating over all elements and invoking 'ToInt64' or the like seems wasteful.

Comment: Curious if this post may be related: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.numeric.general/46855

Answer (score 0):

What I needed was:

```
listValues.tolist() instead of list(listValues)
```

the list() method will keep each element wrapped. This forum post had the answer I was looking for: http://www.python-forum.org/pythonforum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2962&p=12102

I am still curious about the 64bit numpy support though?

Comment: The exception - BadFormatException - is due to trying to load a module of the wrong bitness into the process. It's not clear which module it is. Have you tried debugging it with fusion logging?

Comment: The module is NpyAccessLib.dll