# numpy module cannot be imported, when .py file is used by C#

Tags: c#, python, numpy, ironpython, python.net

[numpy 64bit support in PTVS and numpy System.Int64 casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182735/numpy-64bit-support-in-ptvs-and-numpy-system-int64-casting)

Hello everyone,

I have a Python file which imports numpy and a function inside. When I run this with ironpython through Visual Studio, it works, but when I run it from C# it crashes while running this line:

`dynamic test1 = ipy.UseFile("IronPythonApplication1.py");`

Because it cannot import numpy, this is what I think, because I get this error for a few seconds. Then, the window closes.

It says:

```
"failed while initializing npycoreapi:badimageformat exception 
NumpyDotNet.NpyCoreApi.GetNativeTypeInfo<int32& intSize,............................."
```

This is my Python code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\DLLs')
sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib')
sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages')

import numpy as np

def deneme():
    x = np.arange(100).reshape((10,10))
    return x
```

Comment: Burak, are you found some solution ?

Comment: @JuanPablo have you tried pythonnet?